# Access to shared folder as a virtual directory in the IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, virtual-directory

I have a very simple task on microsoft IIS (Which means 2 days of configuration hell)

I need to add a virtual directory that points to a different server (Shared folder).

I opened a user in the local and the remote servers and I can see the content of the folder, but when I try to copy something to that folder (from the code) I get access denied.

Of course that the user has a full control (shared and ntfs) but not matter what I'm doing I just can't make this simple task to work.

What have I missed? What should I do to make it work?

Thanks in advance - Tal.

Comment: What level of [trust](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772237%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is the app running under?

Comment: I'm not sure that I want to give my app full trust.
However, I did solve this problem by making the app connect as a costume user and grant that user access to to shared folder.

Thanks.

Comment: Write it up as an answer so t gets marked :). Glad your problem got worked out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by changing the appPoolIdentity to a local windows user that has permissions to read\write to the network virtual folder.
The downside (at least from my experience) is performance, the IIS become slow very fast (30 online users in my case).