# MVC - Run different areas under different application pools

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

I need to run different areas in the code under different appPools.
I tried converting the admin area (MVC C#) to application and assign a different appPool but the binaries still run's under to main appPool.

Is there other way to do it?

I thought about making an applications that pointing to the same folder but I'm not sure what will be the consequent. also, if possible I prefer a cleaner solution.

Comment: Why? Do you want them to run under different accounts? Do you have two seperate builds of DLL's etc. that you can isolate to different app pools? How did you try and how do you know it didn't work?

Comment: I need the application pool running for the admin section to have identity of a local windows user and in the other sections as AppPoolIdentity.
I convert the admin area to application and assigned a different application pool but the code still running under the website appPool.

Comment: What do you mean by 'admin area'. Do you mean a whole seperate virtual directory with it's own copy of DLL's etc.?

Comment: The website has back office for admin operations (manage users, content etc), this section in the website need application pool with different identity.

Comment: If I recall how IIS works correctly, in order to have two app pools, you need two different virtual folders. So you'd need to deploy two copies of your app to two different folders then you could assign them different app pools. Are you currently deploying two copies of your app to two different virtual folders?

Comment: If I'm using two websites with two copies of the code than it will work, but I will have to maintain two websites with two different domains.
I'm trying to find cleaner solution.

Comment: It doesn't need to be two websites it just needs to be two virtual folders. Are you currently deploying two copies of your app to two different virtual folders?

Comment: I notice you had this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908601/access-to-shared-folder-as-a-virtual-directory-in-the-iis. I think it would be a good idea to explain what you are doing at a high level. Perhaps there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: If this is related to your other question about accessing remote shares, why do you think you need to split your app into a one component that has access and one that doesn't? Is this a request from the infrastructure team? If only certain people can do this admin task of accessing remote shares, then you should be able to enforce security inside your app to stop unauthorised access.

Comment: I have network folder that I need to access.
If I'm using simple AppPoolIdentity I don't have enough permissions to access that folder.
If I'm using specific user identity I get the permissions that I need but I get performance issues for ~50 users and above.
Since I only need those permissions in the admin area I thought that two separate applications pools can be a good solution but any solution will be great.

Comment: You should understand the performance issue before you make assumptions. The performance issue might be because you are now copying large files over the network, in which case having two app pools will make no difference

Comment: When I'm using specific user identity I get the performance issues immediately (without doing anything is the admin section).
It's probably related to the authentication process that need to verify each request as a windows user (the lsass.exe process is the reason for the performance problems).
Two application pool will solve the issue because in the admin area I have one or two users online top, And the other users can run without the authentication overhead.
I wrote about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326106/application-pool-identity-and-lsass-exe

Comment: It seems to me that if you split your app into two app pools, you are going to get the LSASS.EXE CPU issue regardless and it will still affect performance. I think you should try and solve your LSASS issue as we are getting nowhere trying to explain how to split your app into two app pools.